# Laravel 5.4 Markdown email character issue

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

I'm using Laravel 5.4, I'm sending a Markdown mailable with the following code:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.userWasRegistered')
        ->with('user', $this->user);
}
```

**markdown**

```
@component('mail::message')

    # Welcome

    Thank you for registering, you are registered as a {{ $user->role }}

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
    Login
    @endcomponent

@endcomponent
```

But the output isn't what it's supposed to be, right?

**HTML**

[image]

**HTML source**

[image]

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Where is the table generated from?

Comment: It's the button:  @component

Comment: You need to paste your component markups here.

Comment: Well it's the default from Laravel, any idea where I can find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know what's going on. It's because you indented your template. In markdown when you indent something that's interpreted as a "code-block", which should be displayed as-is instead of computed, if you know what I mean.

```
like this you <strong>see</strong>?
```

So just don't indent your code.

Comment: You're right! Thank god, I would never have tought of that. Thank you!

Comment: God this took me ages to find. Thanks